# Useless tag? [realm-java]

Tags: discussion

The realm thread is explained as:

> Realm is a mobile database replacement for SQLite & Core Data. It is available for Xamarin, Java, Objective-C, React Native and Swift.

So it includes Realm for Java/Android. Yet there is a [realm-java] tag with no explanation and 25 questions.

Should the [realm-java] questions be moved to the [realm] tag, and the [realm-java] tag be deleted?

Comment: From what you've said alone, no; it's got questions under it.  An explanation about the tag can be added later.  Moreover, does the tag describe something ambiguous or off topic?

Comment: But the realm tag by definition includes realm-java. Why not move all realm-java questions to realm and close realm-java? Realm in both of these refers to the mobile database. And the realm tag as I've said is meant to include realm questions in it's Java usage

Comment: It seems like two things should happen: the tag should be synonymized with realm, and existing questions would benefit from editing.